# Issue in Supplying Array Object from Global Function using ES6 and Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-modules

I'm trying to make global function to be able to use same function in different methods.

Here are my codes:

First I created my global js class.

```
import axios from "axios";
class GlobalFunction {
    constructor(){

    }

    async selectNames(name){
        await axios.get(`/Employees/GetName?name=${name}`).then(response=>{ 
            return response.data;
        }).catch(error=>{ console.log(error); });
    }
}

export default GlobalFunction;
```

Second, I imported the global class to my child js file.

```
import GlobalFunction from "./globalfunction.js";

let globalFunction = new GlobalFunction();
```

Third, I wanted to supply specific array object.

```
this.names = globalFunction.selectNames(someName);
```

The problem is, I'm getting a null array in this.names. I already tried to put alert inside the `selectNames(name)` and it's successfully fetching the info. But when I tried to put alert the `globalFunction.selectNames(someName);` it's empty.

Feel free to drop any solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async selectNames(name){
        try }{
          return await axios.get(`/Employees/GetName?name=${name}`);
        catch(err) {
          // err will be the reject'd promise err
        }
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: I forgot to included, yes, I have export there

Comment: what does `sometimes` means there?

Comment: A poor edit ... sorry will fix: globalFunction.selectNames(someName).then(names=>this.names = names);

Comment: I tried this similar to this: `globalFunction.selectNames(someName).then(result=>{this.names=>result});` but it doesn't work

Comment: "but it doesn't work"? did you try: globalFunction.selectNames(someName).then(result=>{console.log(result)});  ?

Comment: it is undefined in this line `console.log(result);` sir

Comment: Async/await was not constructed properly.  Take a look at my new answer.

Comment: should I need to use `return` here `return response.data;`?

Comment: great question.  No, what will be returned is what ever comes from the await'd function. For Axios.get() that will be the response.data automatically.

Comment: Also will add the try catch block so you can see how to handle the reject condition from the axis.get() promise.

Comment: Thank you so much sir :) Now everything works fine. I'm able to use the external or global file to be able to re-use functions inside. :)

Comment: Awesome...so glad to help.